# Can font-size be a % of container size in css/css3?

Tags: css, font-size

I have a container:

```
<div id="container"><h1>LONG TITLE LINE</h1></div>
```

and css:

```
#container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
}

#container h1 {
    font-size: XXXXXX;
}
```

"XXXXXX" <-- where i want the font size to be based on the width of the page/container.

---

QUESTION:  is it possible to have the font-size of the h1 based on the width of the page? in css3? i'm sure it can be done using JS, but like to avoid that if it is possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think it's possible in CSS, but this might be interesting to you:

http://fittextjs.com/

Comment: ohh -- that's pretty. checking out what it does to performance.

Comment: looks good to me -- thanks for the link! now onto the background image :/

Answer (score 6):

An other option dependng on your layout is to use `vw` units :

> vw : 1/100th of the width of the viewport.([source MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths))

If your `#container` width is set as a percentage of the viewport, font-size will adapt to it's width :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Lc3m5/)**

*CSS :*

```
#container h1 {
    font-size: 5vw;
}
```

Browser support for `vw` units is IE9+, see [canIuse](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) for more info.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, it does exactly what the OP was asking for without plugins.

Comment: Exactly what I need without any plugins!

Comment: This is not what OP was asking for. viewport units scale with the viewport (hence their name). What OP (and most likely a lot of others) is looking is scaling basing on a container. Two entirely different things

Comment: @justNik even though this doesn't fully answer OP, it does help others. And it is well specified in the answer "If your #container width is set as a percentage of the viewport..."

Comment: Yes this is certainly helpful, but it should definitely NOT be the accepted answer as others have suggested.

Answer (score 3):

Not the way you are saying. You can, however, do the opposite. Have the width of the page dependent on the font size, if you declare a base font size in ems, then use em values for your layout. Then, the width would increase if you increased the size of the text.

Comment: And then you could set the viewport based upon the rendered page size.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why this couldn't be accomplished using media tags. Depending on how granular you wanted to make it, you could do something like this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1000px){
    #container h1 { font-size:42px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){
    #container h1 { font-size:40px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 900px){
    #container h1 { font-size:35px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px){
    #container h1 { font-size:30px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
    #container h1 { font-size:25px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px){
    #container h1 { font-size:20px; }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
    #container h1 { font-size:15px; }
}
```

See the JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/h9LaD/) for a demo.

Answer (score 0):

My solution creates a CSS variable that expresses the height of the container relative to the viewport, in "vh" units, this variable can then be used with the CSS3 "calc" function to calculate font height as a percentage of the height of the container.

the size of the container is measured every time the viewport (window) is resized

```
<html>
        <head>
            <style>
                .container {
                    width:100%;
                    /*
                        any rules you like to set the dimensions of the container
                    */
                    top:40px;
                    height:30vh;

                    border:1px solid red;
                    white-space:nowrap;
                }
            </style>
            <script>
                    function setCSSVariableAccordingToElementHeightRelativeToViewPort(elementClassName, cssVariableName, immutableElement)
                    {
                        var element
                        /*
                            the "immutableElement" parameter is
                                true when the container is never recreated,
                                false if its generated dynamicaly
                        */
                        if(immutableElement === true) {
                            element = document.querySelector("." + elementClassName)
                        }                   

                        var onResize = function() {
                            if(immutableElement !== true) {
                                element = document.querySelector("." + elementClassName)
                            }

                            if(element != undefined) {
                                var elementHeight = element.offsetHeight
                                var elementVH = (elementHeight / window.innerHeight) * 100
                                element.style.setProperty(cssVariableName, elementVH + "vh")
                            }
                        }
                        onResize()
                        window.onresize = onResize
                    }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <span style="font-size:calc(var(--container-vh) * 0.25)">25%</span>
                <span style="font-size:calc(var(--container-vh) * 0.50)">50%</span>
                <span style="font-size:calc(var(--container-vh) * 1.00)">100%</span>
            </div>
        </body>

        <script>
            setCSSVariableAccordingToElementHeightRelativeToViewPort("container", "--container-vh", true)
        </script>
    </html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martijn_s/xomp46oy/)